# how to sort the elements in a list in numerical order and not alphabetical

Tags: python, sorting

i have a list containing sentences with numbers in it, i want to sort then numerically and not alphabetically. but when i use the sort function, it sorts the elements alphabetically and not numerically, how do i fix this?

```
num = ['ryan has 8 apples','charles has 16 bananas','mylah has 3 watermelons']
num.sort()
print(num)

output:
['charles.....','mylah.....','ryan......']
```

as you can see, it is sorted alphabetically but that is not my expected output

the dots represent the rest of the sentence

```
expected result:

['mylah has 3 watermelons','ryan has 8 apples','charles has 16 bananas']
```

here's the expected output where the elements are sorted numerically and not alphabetically

Comment: I don't see why you'd expect Python to magically guess you want to use a number from somewhere inside the string to order them. Read e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html for guidance.

Comment: That seems a bit harsh :(  OP doesn't say that Python is doing anything wrong, they're just asking what python features would produce a solution like they're looking for.

Comment: is there only 1 number iin the string or multiple ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a key to sort them on that splits the string and parses the number as a number to sort, you can also then sort alphabetically if you wish for those with the same number.

```
sorted(num, key=lambda x: (int(x.split()[2]), x))
```

or

```
num.sort(key=lambda x: (int(x.split()[2]), x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`key=`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to let `sort` know which value you want to assign each element for sorting.

If the strings are always that structured, you can use:

```py
num = ['ryan has 8 apples','charles has 16 bananas','mylah has 3 watermelons']
num.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split(' ')[2]))
print(num)
```

If they are more complex, take a look at regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions so far focus on a solution specific to the structure of your strings but would fail for slightly different string structures.  If we extract only the digit parts of the string and then convert to an `int`, we'll get a value that we can pass to the sort function's key parameter:

```py
num.sort(
    key=lambda s: int(''.join(c for c in s if c.isdigit()))
)
```

The key parameter lets you specify some alternative aspect of your datum to sort by, in this case, a value provided by the lambda function.

Comment: If it were a different structure then your answer would also be just as susceptible, i.e  "joe has 3 apples and 4 oranges"

Comment: yeah, totally true!  at some point, it's impossible to tackle all possible variations and you have to determine what the domain of the problem is.